# Horizontal boxes alignment with minipage

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

I'm trying to align 2 boxes horizontally. I would like the left one to start at the far left and the right one to start at the far right.

```
\begin{titlepage}
    \begin{center}
      \vspace*{1cm}
      {\tiny \hrule height 0.001pt}
      \vspace{5pt}
      \setlength{\baselineskip}{1.5\baselineskip} \textsf{{\LARGE Title}} \par
      \vspace{13pt}
      {\tiny \hrule height 0.01pt}
      \large\texttt{Some name}\\
      \vfill
      \large\textit{some text}
      \vspace{2cm}
      {\tiny \hrule height 0.001pt}
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
         \begin{center}
            \emph{text}
            \begin{center}
                test
            \end{center}
         \end{center}
      \end{minipage}    
      \begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\textwidth}    
         \begin{framed}    
             \begin{center}    
                 \emph{text}
             \end{center}    
         \end{framed}    
      \end{minipage}            
      \vspace{2cm}          
      \large Some random text   
   \end{center}    
\end{titlepage}
```

I tried `flushleft` but it doesn't seem to work the way I wish. I'm also wondering why the framed one doesn't take the same space as the not framed one.

I added the last hrule to show where I would like my left minipage to start (at the left) and my right minipage to end (at the right).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put a `\hfill` between the two minipages. That will probably solve it. As for the extra space, I guess it is the extra spaces around the `framed`. If you make it into a [complete working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) we can try it out, instead of guessing.

Comment: I provided as much details as I could. It only lacked ``\begin{document}`` and ``\end{document}`` but I left it that way because I didn't know if the ``\input{titlepage}`` in the original document has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

`\hfill` solved the problem. Now it fills the page's width.